# Optimize looping over a large string to reduce allocations

Tags: julia

I am trying to loop over a string in Julia to parse it. I have a DefaultDict inside a struct, containing the number of times I have seen a particular character.

```
@with_kw mutable struct Metrics
    ...
    nucleotides = DefaultDict{Char, Int64}(0)
    ...
end
```

I have written a function to loop over a string and increment the value of each character in the DefaultDict.

```
function compute_base_composition(sequence::String, metrics::Metrics)
    for i in 1:sizeof(sequence)
        metrics.nucleotides[sequence[i]] += 1
    end
end
```

This function is called in a for loop because I need to do this for multiple strings (which can be up to 2 billions characters long). When I run the @time macro, I get this result:

```
@time compute_base_composition(sequence, metrics)
  0.167172 seconds (606.20 k allocations: 15.559 MiB, 78.00% compilation time)
  0.099403 seconds (1.63 M allocations: 24.816 MiB)
  0.032346 seconds (633.24 k allocations: 9.663 MiB)
  0.171382 seconds (3.06 M allocations: 46.751 MiB, 4.64% gc time)
```

As you can see, there are a lot of memory allocations for such a simple function. I have tried to change the for loop to something like `for c in sequence` but that didn't change much. Would there be a way to reduce them and make the function faster?

Comment: Are these 4 lines from repeated runs of the `@time` macro without code changes? I only get similar numbers on the first run, and that's 99.1% compilation time (and presumably, compiler allocations too). Subsequent runs allocate only about 1 KB.

Comment: the compute_base_composition function is called in a for loop, the @time outputs are from the first calls to this function.

Comment: The varying allocations in the 2nd-4th runs is weird, are you doing different strings per iteration? As for my 2 cents, my guess would be 1) there are so many different characters that the dictionary is expanded often and has to be frequently reallocated to a bigger memory chunk, or 2) getting a Char `sequence[i]` is allocating. 1) is kind of doubtful because most text just uses ASCII, and 2) is very doubtful because small primitive types are stack-allocated.

Comment: What do you mean by "from the first calls to this function"? Perhaps you should just paste the for loop too here, a minimum example that replicates these allocations.

Comment: It's hard to help with so little information. Can you provide a small, but fully runnable example, including dummy input data (or  code that will generate the dummy input)?

Comment: Have you looked at BioJulia? It probably has better tools to do this type of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Work on bytes no on unicode chars
2. Use `Vector`s not `Dict`s
3. Avoid untyped fields in containers

```
@with_kw struct MetricsB
    nucleotides::Vector{Int}=zeros(Int, 256)
end

function compute_base_composition(sequence::String, metrics::MetricsB)
    bs = Vector{UInt8}(sequence)
    for i in 1:length(bs)
        @inbounds metrics.nucleotides[bs[i]] += 1
    end
end
```

And a benchmark with a nice speedup of 90x :

```
julia> st = randstring(10_000_000);

julia> @time compute_base_composition(st, Metrics())
  1.793991 seconds (19.94 M allocations: 304.213 MiB, 3.33% gc time)

julia> @time compute_base_composition(st, MetricsB())
  0.019398 seconds (3 allocations: 9.539 MiB)
```

Actually you can almost totally avoid allocations with the following code:

```
function compute_base_composition2(sequence::String, metrics::MetricsB)
    pp = pointer(sequence)
    for i in 1:length(sequence)
        @inbounds metrics.nucleotides[Base.pointerref(pp, i, 1)] += 1
    end
end
```

and now:

```
julia> @time compute_base_composition2(st, MetricsB())
  0.021161 seconds (1 allocation: 2.125 KiB)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am pretty new to Julia and your solution and explanations are great!